# What can one say about the precision of the experiment if horizontal error-bars are wide and vertical error-bars are very small?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, experimental-physics, error-analysis

After conducting a physics experiment I plotted the data with their respective uncertainties. My horizontal error-bars for the independent variable are wide but vertical error-bars for the dependent variable are very small. What can I say about the precision? I then am finding the slope of the graph and corresponding uncertainty which yields 30% percentage error, meaning low precision for the slope. However, standard deviations achieved for the dependent variable are very low indicating high precision of measurements of the dependent variable. Am I allowed to say that there is high precision in the dependent variable but low in the slope due to wide horizontal error bars - poor precision in measurement of the independent variable.

Comment: If the aim is t find the gradient of the graph or a relationship between the two variables then the errors of both the dependent and independent variables must be taken into account.

Comment: Beware that standard least squares or chi-squared minimisation methods assume negligible uncertainty in the x values.

Comment: It would help if you provided some context. Maybe show us the plot you generated. However, independent of the context the words "high" and "low" are usually not informative, if they are not accompanied by a reference value. Thus, consider saying something like "the uncertainty of the slope is dominated by the uncertainty of x".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can certainly state that "that there is high precision in the dependent variable but low in the slope due to wide horizontal error bars - poor precision  - in measurement of the independent variable.", since that is the result of your experiment.  There is no reason the horizontal independent variable errors have to be smaller than the vertical dependent variable errors, it is just often the case. (And is usually the case for undergraduate lab experiments because of how those experiments are designed.)